# Why Foursquare venue search api omits some results when using parent category id but shows them when child category id is used?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to narrow down foursquare venue search api results by specifying category ids. 
when I try a parent category id like "Food" with id `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259` the result does not contain some of restaurants with child category id "Fast Food Restaurant" with id `4bf58dd8d48988d16e941735`" but when searching with child category id omitted restaurants show in search results.
I think when a parent category id is specified the result must contain all results with all child category ids? is this true or I'm missing something?
thanks

edit: setting intent = browse seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> edit: setting intent = browse seems to solve my problem.

Yes, you should set `intent = browse` because default value is `checkin`.

`checkin` finds venues that the current user is likely to checkin to at the provided `ll`, at the current moment in time.

`browse` find venues within a given area. Unlike the `checkin` intent, `browse` searches an entire region instead of only finding venues closest to a point.

See also https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search